# Не получается правильно создать форму с помощью двух radio кнопок

Tags: php, html, php7

Нужно ,чтобы при отправки формы приходил соответствующий ответ.
"Спросите у пользователя знает ли он PHP с помощью двух radio кнопок.".Проблема в том,что если нажать нет или ничего не нажать, выдаст одинаковое  сообщение "Поздравляю , вы не знаете php".По задумке так не должно быть.
Мой код такой .

```
<br>Вы знаете PHP  ?<br><br>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="radio" hidden="radio1" value=""/>
Да<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="on" />
<input type="radio" hidden="radio2" value=""/>
Нет<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="on" /><br><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Отправить</button>
</form>


<?php

if(!empty($_REQUEST) and $_REQUEST['radio1'] == "on"){
    echo "Поздравляю ,вы знаете PHP";
}
elseif(!empty($_REQUEST) and $_REQUEST['radio1'] == ""){
    echo "Вы не выбрали кнопку!!!";
}elseif(!empty($_REQUEST) and $_REQUEST['radio2'] == "on"){
    echo "Поздравляю , вы не знаете php";
}elseif(!empty($_REQUEST) and $_REQUEST['radio2'] == ""){
    echo "Вы не выбрали кнопку!!!";
}


var_dump($_REQUEST);

include_once "footer.php";

?>
```

Comment: Совершенно неправильно сделаны кнопки. Для начала у них должно быть одинаковое имя. А сейчас можно выбрать обе одновременно.

Comment: Делаешь три кнопки, самую первую кнопку делаешь с атрибутом checked, а остальные как у тебя, только value поменяй. И атрибут name у всех трех одинаковые, а затем делаешь проверки.

Comment: @Евгений Зачем три, если надо две?

Comment: @Эникейщик Третья нужна для обратной связи с сервером .Чтобы он понимал ,что происходит. У неё type будет hidden
    <input type="hidden" name="radio" value=""/>

Comment: @ВасилийРайлян Что она даст? О какой обратной связи речь?

Comment: @Эникейщик  Скрывает содержимое элемента от просмотра. Такой элемент не отображается на странице, но доступен через скрипты.
Иногда на сервер нужно передать данные, которые сервер сам и сгенерировал. Если понять то, что каждый запрос к веб серверу - это независимый запрос, то серверной части нужно оставлять какие то метки для себя.

Comment: Это все понятно, но какое отношение это имеет к данному конкретному вопросу?

Comment: Ах да)) Все правильно) я не о том думал)

Answer (score 2):

Радиокнопка должна иметь **одно** имя, и **несколько** вариантов значений - это была основная ошибка:

```
$k = join(array_values($_REQUEST)) ?: 'default';

$questions = [
    'on' => 'Поздравляю, вы знаете PHP!',
    'off' => 'Поздравляю, вы не знаете PHP!',
    'default' => 'Вы знаете PHP?'
];

?>

<?= $questions[$k] ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    Да<input type="radio" name="radio" value="on" />
    Нет<input type="radio" name="radio" value="off" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```